# Authenticating a power bi web app using OAuth2.0 and AAD

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am following this "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt186158.aspx" article to create a PowerBi webapp for displaying reports. I need to get the access token to access Power Bi Rest Apis for which i am using Oauth2.0 authorization. I have followed all the steps correctly but still getting error while using AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenUsingAuthorizationCode(...).

Error: invalid_grant

Server responded with 400 error.Bad request.

{"AADSTS70000: Authentication failed: Authorization Code is malformed or invalid.\r\nTrace ID: 3d40b7a8-90fa-429a-9616-abcb94262c5b\r\nCorrelation ID: a34f987e-7ed0-4f6c-bec3-5060a5b834ea\r\nTimestamp: 2015-12-14 10:45:34Z"}
System.Exception {Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException}

Now,I have googled a lot regarding this error but couldn't find anything useful. I have verified the consistency of Redirect_Url.i have configured my web appliaction to access powerBI. In short I have checked everything for correctness.

plz help me with this issue.It is a blocking bug for my application. Also, if there is any other way to get access token in my web application to use Power BI Apis,plz suggest.

Comment: If you verified that everything is set up correctly, the best course of action at this point is to look at the request/responses traces to verify whether there's any wire getting crossed (like the string used as code actually being the authorization code returned by Azure AD). Can you capture a fiddler trace and post the relevant fragments?